# How to build something like RSForm in Joomla for an application?

Tags: joomla, laravel-4

I have an application in Laravel 4.2 and I want to know how can I write such a sub-project app like RSForm builder in joomla for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution with front-end(Vue.JS) in below discussion:

[Laravel create dynamic forms via a drag and drop interface](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/laravel-create-dynamic-forms-via-a-drag-and-drop-interface?page=2)